# Error Term, Regression

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, regression, linear-regression

Assume I have $Y_i=A+BX_i + \epsilon_i$
For a multiple linear regression I have,

$Y_i=A+B_1X_1+B_2X_2+....+B_NX_N+\epsilon$ 
The question is, what is the distribution of $\epsilon$, knowing that $\epsilon_i$ is distributed with mean 0 and variance $K^2$?

Comment: What you have written may have an error or two.  For example the second part has $A$ and $A^2$ but I doubt they are related.  You may have intended the second equation to be something like $Y_i=A+B_1X_{1,i}+B_2X_{2,i}+\cdots+B_NX_{N,i}+\epsilon_i$

Comment: @Henry, You're Correct, they aren't related. I renamed the letter A to K.